# Fetch particular field from moodialog and pass value to parent screen

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, mootools

I used MooDialog.iframe and onClose i need some values. But not able to fetch values from that iFrame and want to use in the page i opened this frame in popup.

The function/code i used for popup is below:

```
function popup_window() {
    var hostname = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname +       (location.port && ":" + location.port) + "/";
    var opcion = "crear";
    co2=new MooDialog.IFrame(hostname+'infinity/contabilidad/cuenta%20crear/popup_window.php?action=2',
        { 
            title: 'Editar Centro','class' : 'content_edit1 MooDialog',
            onClose: function()
            {   
                /////////alert(document.getElementById('numero_cuenta').value);
//numero_cuenta is something i want
                location.reload();                                                                          
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**numero_cuenta** is the id of the input.text of the popup iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

From the popup_window.php file get the element by id via frame. We need to use the following code:

```
onClose: function()
{   
    var myIFrame = document.getElementById("MooFrame");
    var content = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementById('abcd').value;

    alert('content: ' + content);   

    location.reload();                                                                          
}
```